# is there any API to get image from wiki page

Tags: python, wikipedia, dbpedia

I want to get main image from wikipedia page, I have all wikipedia entity name from which I create wiki link and getting main image from that page.

I tried with

https://github.com/richardasaurus/wiki-api, https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia

But this does not work on all pages though page contains image.

```
from wikiapi import WikiApi
wiki = WikiApi()
wiki = WikiApi({ 'locale' : 'es'})
def getWikiImage(entity):
    results = wiki.find(entity)
    print results
    if len(results):
        article = wiki.get_article(results[0])
        print article.image
#getWikiImage("Rudy Sarzo")
getWikiImage("Melody Gersbach")
```

mediawiki api at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Python I checked out, but does not seem to help.

Comment: On what page does this *not* work?

Comment: @LutzHorn: please check updated descriptio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is little example how to get wikipage and main image should be the first one on the page.

```
import wikipedia

PAGES = ['New York', 'Mercury_(planet)', 'Tucana']

for page in PAGES:
    wikipage = wikipedia.page(page)
    print "Page Title: %s" % wikipage.title
    print "Page URL: %s" % wikipage.url
    print "Nr. of images on page: %d" % len(wikipage.images)
    print " - Main Image: %s" % wikipage.images[0]
    print ""
```

Checkout out [Quickstart guide for Wikipedia API.](https://wikipedia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: Seems like `wikipage.images[0]` doesn't return the main image (upper right) now, but it returns random picture from the article

Comment: @DmytroSytro I know this is two years ago but did you find a way to get the main image and not a random

Comment: @GILO Yeah, check my answer

Answer (score 15):

This returns the url of the main image of the article, not the random one:

```
import wikipedia
import requests
import json

WIKI_REQUEST = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&titles='

def get_wiki_image(search_term):
    try:
        result = wikipedia.search(search_term, results = 1)
        wikipedia.set_lang('en')
        wkpage = wikipedia.WikipediaPage(title = result[0])
        title = wkpage.title
        response  = requests.get(WIKI_REQUEST+title)
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        img_link = list(json_data['query']['pages'].values())[0]['original']['source']
        return img_link        
    except:
        return 0

wiki_image = get_wiki_image('Paris City')
```